# C++ Win API Как получить обьект из другого потока?

Tags: c++, winapi

Создаю поток методом CreateThread. Как из основного потока получить доступ к обьекту созданому во втором потоке и вызвать его метод?

Comment: Так же как будто он создан в основном потоке, только аккуратней

Comment: Если к объекту осуществляется доступ только из одного потока, то проблем нет. Если к объекту осуществляется доступ из нескольких потоков, то нужно защищать объект семафорами или другими способами межпотоковой синхронизации.

Comment: Во второй поток передаем коллбэк (функцию + ивент). 1й поток после создания второго становится в ожидание ивента. 2й поток создает объект, в коллбэке передает его адрес/ссылку первому потоку и активирует ивент, далее, если объект создается не в динамике второй поток должен жить до тех пор, пока нужен доступ к объекту (иначе будет уб). Первый поток после ожидания ивента может работать с объектом. Как правило, если возникают такие кейсы, то лучше создать третью сущность, типа пула объектов, к которой будут обращаться оба потока, а сама сущность будет контролировать права доступа и синхронизацию.